# bscan values for Tilde and Pipe in keybd_event

Tags: vb.net

I have this declaration:

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, 
          ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, 
          ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)
```

and I'm using these calls:

for ` and ~

```
Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Oemtilde, &H29, 1, 0)
Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Oemtilde, &H29, 3, 0)
```

for \ and |

```
Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.OemPipe, &H43, 1, 0)
Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.OemPipe, &H43, 3, 0)
```

I made my best guesses from searching online to be &H29 and &H43, but I fear these are wrong even though my program sends the proper keyboard events. Do these values even matter?

Comment: see the [PInvoke for keybd_event](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/keybd_event.html)

Comment: thank you for formatting my question, but your link tells me nothing about the bScan argument... every call has "0x45", but doesn't explain why

Comment: I'm able to find the codes for many keys here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?277384-VB-Key-COnsts but not the tilde or pipe